# windows prompt compare and remove files

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I have a Command Prompt question, hopefully you can help me out..
I have a file-list in a certain directory where i want to remove only the old files which are optimized.
So for the following list only theses files should be removed: [file2.ifc / file5.ifc / mainpart.ifc]

```
file1.ifc
file2.ifc
file2_optimized.ifc
file3.ifc
file4.ifc
file5.ifc
file5_optimized.ifc
mainpart.ifc
mainpart_optimized.ifc
```

How can this be achieved?

Thanx in advance,

Loek

Comment: It can be achieved by writing a short script to accomplish this task. (What does your script look like so far? What have you tried, and with what results?)

Comment: The `%~` operators will let you decompose a file name into components. Type `for /?` for more details.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please make sure your code provides a [mimimal and reproduceable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List all `.ifc` files, filter (exclude) the `_optimized` files and for the rest check if an `_optimized` file exists and if yes, delete the file:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.ifc^|findstr /vie "_optimized.ifc"') do (
   if exist "%%~na_optimized%%~xa" del "%%a"
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the List of ifc Files in the directory, that do not contain "_Optimized.ifc" at the ned, and simply check if one with "_Optimized.ifc" DOES exist in the directly, if it does, delete it.

### You can do this on the cMD CLI Directly with:

```
FOR %A IN (
  "C:\Folder\Path\*.ifc"
) DO (
  ECHO=%~nx_FIND /V /I "_Optimized.ifc" && (
    IF EXIST "%~dpnA_Optimized.ifc" (
      DEL /F /Q "%~fA"
    )
  )
)
```